# WPF shared EventTrigger

Tags: wpf

I have a window with a TabControl containing two TabItems (let's call them "A" and "B"). Tab A has several ContextMenus: I would like every MenuItem to change the TabItem to Tab B. Ideally I would write one MenuItem template that would switch the tab when a MenuItem is selected. Is this possible?

EDIT:
The solution I ended up using relies on MenuItems in the ContextMenus deriving from a base style which defines the click event and handler:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="ContextMenuItemBase">
         ... (various stylings)
         <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_Clicked"/>
      </Style>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I named the tab control and tab item I want to switch to:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tcTabs">
...
   <TabItem Header="Results" x:Name="tiResultsTab">
```

Then in the MainWindow.xaml.cs code-behind file:

```
private void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   tcTabs.SelectedItem = tiResultsTab;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for...Tab A's contect menu's need to change the tab to display tab B. Can you reword/write your sitation?

Comment: Yes... Tab A's context menus need to change the tab to display Tab B when one of their menu items is pressed.

Comment: What is stopping you from subscribing to the event and changing to Tab B?

Comment: I'm just wondering what the minimum amount of WPF (and hopefully no code-behind) would be to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the menu selection event. Inside the method which handles the operation then extract *which menu* called via the method arguments which identifies the `Sender` (possibly mark the `Tag` property with the other tab's reference(?)). Then change to the appropriate target Tab.

Comment: So there is no pure XAML solution? I'll always need a code-behind?

Comment: @riqitang provide a small example app for us to work off of. There are too many variables AFAIK that may/may not hamper a proper answer. Nothing is worse than working on a solution only to have the OP say, "But that is not like my system".  :-)

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I got it to work using minimal code, I'll edit the OP with the "solution" and mark this answer as accepted (since the solution's based off of it)